# What is the best way to implement Azure AD authentication for .NET 7 microservices hosted within Azure Kubernetes Service?

Tags: angular, azure, authentication, azure-aks, azure-ad-msal

I have a monolith app with the following :

1. Angular FrontEnd (Version : 12) hosted in Azure App Service
2. Monolithic Backend (ASP.NET CORE 3.1) hosted in separate Azure App Service
3. Azure SQL

At present the security is implemented using the guidelines mentioned at : https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/azure-ad-integration-with-angular-and-asp-net-core-web-api

As part of app modernization, I am trying to leverage Microservices architecture for this application.

Here goes the high level design :

1. Angular FrontEnd (Version : 12) hosted in Azure App Service
2. Break the entire backend into 5 to 6 microservices and host them in Azure Kubernetes Service
3. Leverage Azure SQL for database

The backend microservices will be containerized and hosted within Azure Kubernetes service.
All these services also have access other Azure PaaS service like Azure SQL , Azure Redis cache, Azure Key Vault and few more including integration with other third party services. The whole setup will be hosted in 3 regions. I do have few concerns in context to security. Is it ok to go with integrating Azure AD in the Angular frontend, have JWT injected in backend requests there and just validate the JWT in the backend microservices (done in the old design) or is there any better approach to deal with this issue ?

I also came across this article : https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/securing-your-aks-deployments-microservice-user-authentication/ba-p/3823867

but still wanted to know is there any better way to deal with security implementation.

Comment: _"Is it ok to go with integrating Azure AD in the Angular frontend"_ - that depends on whether or not you're referring to OIDC's `implicit` flow or not.

Comment: _"have JWT injected in backend requests"_ - what do you mean by an "injected" JWT, exactly? (Are you referring to the "BFF pattern"?)

Comment: In this case there is only one Frontend app which will be using the microservices. Apart from this thin client there are no other consumers and hence not sure we need BFF pattern here. Apologies from my side in case I have created any confusion in describing the question. All I need is a standard way of implementing security with Azure AD for all the microservices hosted within Azure Kubernetes Service

Comment: AzureAD uses OIDC, and OIDC pretty-much requires the BFF pattern for SPAs like Angular now, because `implicit` flow is now considered too insecure for use.